Civicrm on wordpress - Twilio sms not working
After following the Twilio sms setup instructions from this link https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/sms-text-messaging/set-up/, I encountered the following error in the Twilio console:
(Error 21614) 'To' number is not a valid mobile number
In my Civicrm contact information, I have entered + followed by country code followed by mobile number.
How to check if Civicrm is using E164 format for the mobile number?
What else can be wrong here?
What is Civisms ? Is it a valid Civicrm extension? What does it do? Why does it not appear as one of the extensions in the 5.72.1 version of the Civicrm Wordpress install?

When developers publish extensions there is no obligation on them to do so in a way that means they are listed as 'available for download' via the CiviCRM UI. Perhaps provide a link to what you are referring to. Only reference i see to civisms is here which implies, to me, it maybe part of core https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/sms-text-messaging/set-up/#testing-civisms

I know we did a bunch for one client to set up validation of new phone numbers so they all met the requirement. Perhaps give an anon example of what you are using that doesn't work
